# An example of a bootstrapper file?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, bootstrapping

Does anyone have a good example of a bootstrapper class I can see for reference..

I can't seem to find one anywhere, searched google but no luck.

Searched the helpfile and no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for a class that that configures the container at the beggining of an application, you can download the latest [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/53942) drop and look for the UnityBootstrapper class.

Take into account that this is only registering the necessary services for a Prism application to run, so your bootstrapper will probably require a different container configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can find another example in the [WPF:MVVM & Unity](http://mvvmandunity.codeplex.com/) Kiosk sample project. Here the Bootsrapper class:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public Bootstrapper(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public Bootstrapper RegisterModule(Type moduleType)
    {
        IModule module = container.Resolve(moduleType) as IModule;
        if (module == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("moduleType");
        module.Register(container);
        return this;
    }
    private IUnityContainer container;
}
```

And the IModule interface:

```
public interface IModule
{
    void Register(IUnityContainer container);
}
```

Finally, One of the implemented Modules:

```
public class PhotoEditorModule : IModule
{
    public void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // register default controller
        container.RegisterType<IPhotoEditor, Controller>();
        // register view models
        container.RegisterType<IPhotoEditorViewModel, PhotoEditorViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IPhotoEditorMenuViewModel, PhotoEditorMenuViewModel>();
    }
}
```