# C# WPF MVVM Pattern Logic and UI seperated where the logic for app.config

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use MVVM light with mvvm pattern in my C# WPF application. The UI (Views) and logic is seperated, means the Logic (ViewModels, Models, DAL etc.) is in a DLL, but I'm not aware, where I have to store my logic to read the appsettings which are stored in the App.config of the UI.

Solution 1: 
MainViewModel has the logic inside, because is logic to read the app.config

Solution 2:
Mainwindow.xaml.cs has the methods inside.

One more question raised up:

If you use in your project a DataAccessLayer do you store the class in your Project where are the viewmodels and models (Buisness logic) are located or do you seperate the DAL in a new class libaray and use the DLL in your viewmodels?

Comment: There is but one appsettings for any application and it is defined within the project that creates the .exe file.  Any referenced assembly can read from that appsettings at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where I have to store my logic to read the appsettings which are stored in the App.config of the UI?

If you read these settings directly when your application starts up I would typically implement this logic in a Bootstrapper class that is invoked from the OnStartup method of the App.xaml.cs class.

[An example of a bootstrapper file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001578/an-example-of-a-bootstrapper-file)

If you read the setting later at runtime you should probably implement the logic in the view model. A window/view shouldn't contain any application logic - only purely view-related logic.

> If you use in your project a DataAccessLayer do you store the class in your Project where are the viewmodels and models (Buisness logic) are located or do you seperate the DAL in a new class libaray and use the DLL in your viewmodels?

The DAL (including the class(es) that access the database) should be defined in a class library of its own. You could then reference this assembly from your project where the view models are defined.